# Disable web.config inheritance for individual child applications

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there a way of disabling child web.config inheritance for individual child applications?

I am aware of `inheritInChildApplications="false"` but this is applied to the root web.config and affects ALL child web applications. What if you need to disable inheritance for a single web application (or a specific list of child applications) and keep it for others?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your root `web.config` just before the closing `</configuration>` element:

```
<location path="myapp" inheritInChildApplications="false" />
```

Where `myapp` is the child application you wish to disable configuration inheritance for.

Comment: Thanks, will test and if it works upvote and accept.

Comment: @DeanKuga - any joy?

Comment: Didn't work for me, once I removed location sections enclosing root web.config lines incompatible with my app and adding this line to the bottom of root web.config, my app reverted to processing lines from root web.config and throwing exceptions...